# Class in Nodejs does not return expected value when using parameter

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a class on my node server, each function of it returns something from another api, the *first function* that I will show *does not use a parameter*, it **returns the items correctly**, the *second that uses the Make parameter*, **does not return anything**, and does not point out error

**function getInventory:**
*(this function works normally)*

```
async getInventory() {
    try {
        let res = await axios.get(URL);
        let data = res.data;
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }    
}
```

**function getMakesNew(make):** *(this function works without errors but does not return anything)*

```
async getMakesNew(make) {             
        try {
            let res = await axios.get(URL);
            let data = res.data;
            let count = 0;
        
            while (data != make) {
                if (data[count].ID === make) {
                    return data[count].Name;
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }        
    }
```

**Calling the two functions on the routes:**

```
// GetInventory
routes.get('/getInventory', async (req, res) => {
    return res.json(await Vehicle.getInventory());
});

// getMakesNew
routes.get('/getMakesNew/:make', async (req, res) => {
    let { make } = req.params;
    return res.json(await Vehicle.getMakesNew(make));
});
```

**function getMakesNew returns:**

```
{}
```

Comment: `try` and `while (data != make) {` isn't the best approach to handle an axios call, anyway try to debug the `res` variable, it should show some more info

Comment: what is the correct form? I believe the problem is in this, I debugged the res and everything is returning normal, even with parameters

Comment: If `data` never equals `make` you have an infinite loop.

Comment: yes, but it breaks on the return, or not?

Comment: @GustavoMello If it ever does return... Instead of count++ return something there to test. Your while loop isn't doing anything other than counting infinitely if your condition is not true.

Comment: I passed a condition that stops the loop
`while (data[count].ID != make)`
but still doesn't return anything

Comment: What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

return keyword is missing from your second function